# Style results of ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, opencart

I have recently been faced with a problem. I have a script that adds an item to shopping cart of my Opencart via ajax post and adds the results into a div. However I seem to be getting a response that is different of the set response which is

```
"Success: You have added <a href="%s">%s</a> to your <a href="%s">shopping cart</a>!"
```

This is the response that I am getting in my div:

```
{"success":"Success: You have added
<a href="\"http:\/\/mystore.org\/store\/index.php?route=product\/product&product_id=50\"">
Apple<\/a> to your</a><a href="\"http:\/\/mystore.org\/store\/index.php?route=checkout\/cart\"">
shopping cart<\/a>!","total":"3 item(s) - $20.99"}
</a>
```

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#addform").submit(function() {
    $.post($("#addform").attr("action"), $("#addform").serialize(), function(data){
    $("#result").empty().slideDown("slow").append(data);
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

I am just a beginner so if possible please provide detail.

Thank you very much

Comment: Getting rid of "" results in absolutely same response. Adding success results in no response but the item is added to the cart so the form is received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a json response, to get the success message you need this -

```
$("#addform").submit(function() {
    $.post($("#addform").attr("action"), $("#addform").serialize(), function(data){

    // parse json response
    data = $.parseJSON(data);  

    // get success message with data.success and append it to results
    $("#result").empty().slideDown("slow").append(data.success);
    });
    return false;
});
```